# GIT Is it possible to push directly to the subdirectory?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

My remote repository looks like this.

main - example/
file1
file2

user1 -        file1
file2

user2 - example/
file1
file2

I'm doing some projects with my friend on git and we have each branches and trying to merge branch to main.
Because of the server root directory configuration, user1 has to keep that status excluding the example folder.

I found the way to just pull files from main branch using git sparse checkout but I'm not sure it also works when user1 do push things.

I mean let's say user1 do

git config core.sparseCheckout true

echo "example/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

git pull origin main

git push origin main

What happens if user1 do push origin main? Does main branch keep the example folder or not? If not, is there a way to just push to the example directory? Please help

Comment: Are `main`, `user1`, and `user2` branches?

Comment: Yes they are branches!

Comment: `user1` isn't described like a branch. It sounds more like you have one branch but repositories with two different behaviors when pulling from that branch.

Comment: Git doesn't push or pull files. The folder must be added and then committed first.

Comment: I didn't explain that we merge user1 branch to main branch before pull it. So it is impossible.. thx

Comment: It’s impossible because that’s not how git works.